# Uniqueness up to unique isomorphism of quasi inverse of an arrow in a strict 2-category

Tags: category-theory, 2-categories

I just started to learn the basics of strict 2-categories, and reading some notes I've found the following simple proposition:

> Let **C** be a strict 2-category, and $F:X \rightarrow Y$ a 1-cell (i.e. a morphism between two objects of **C**). We say that $F$ is an *equivalence* if $\exists$ $G:Y\rightarrow X$ such that we have two 2-cells $\eta :F\circ G\Rightarrow 1_{Y}$ and $\epsilon : G\circ F$ $\Rightarrow$ $1_{X}$ which are isomorphisms. In this case $G$ is called a *quasi-inverse* of $F$, and it is unique up to unique isomorphism.

I've shown that the quasi-inverse is unique up to isomorphism (if $H:Y\rightarrow X$ is another one, then $(G\ast\eta')\cdot(\epsilon^{-1}\ast H) : H\Rightarrow G$ is an isomorphism, where $\eta':F\circ H\Rightarrow 1_{Y}$ is the 2-cell given by the definition, $\cdot$ is the vertical composition of 2-cells and $\ast$ is the horizontal), but I don't see why this should be unique. Can anybody help me?

Comment: I don't think it's unique, for instance a quasi-inverse could have nontrivial automorphisms. I think it's rather "unique up to unique commuting isomorphism", or something along these lines